# conemu - custom console panels layout

Tags: conemu

I'm trying to arrange my conemu panels in a specific way. I only managed to get 2/3 of the panels to be arranged as i'd like, but i can't figure out how to do the last part.

The layout i'm after is something like this:

[image]

but i only managed to get two panels split horizontally and the third one opens on a new (fullscreen) panel in a different tab.

How can i achive this?
The task parameters i'm using are the following:

```
title GIT -new_console:12T50H:P:"Dracula" & cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" && cd c:\src\www 

title Website -new_console:12T50V:P:"Dracula" & cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" && cd c:\src\www 

title DYS -new_console:s2T50V:P:"Monokai - Custom" & cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" && cd c:\src\dys
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic. Only one simple rule: each "split" divides the pane in two.
You made two mistakes. First pane can't be a split - it's completely new console covering 100% of surface. In the second split you missed `s` modifer.

```
-new_console:t:"GIT":P:"Dracula":d:"c:\src\www" & cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"

-new_console:t:"Website":s1T50H:P:"Dracula":d:"c:\src\www" & cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"

-new_console:t:"DYS":s1T50V:P:"Monokai - Custom":d:"c:\src\dys" & cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"
```

[image: split rule]